# combine dates into 1 and combine other cells (amounts) into 1 cell in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

i have a question i use GOOGLE SHEETS and i get data from a APi into my sheets it uploads orders  with the DATE of order and with a amount of the order.

now if i get 10 orders i get 10 rows of say like (21-7-2015) and a amount

i want an automated process that combines these order dates and amounts 
so if i get 10 orders for 1 euro on 27-7-2015 it should have 1 row of 21-7-2015 in A1 the DATE Colum and G5 ( in my case should have the total amount of 10) 
10x 1 euro combined

now the trick is . i am not sure if i am getting 5 orders per day or 10 
so it should only combine if the DATES are the same

i hope i can make myself clear about what i would like it to do. 
please see the layout here

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJ6FjRzt9TMYKkK41cRSzA4cl8dBhoIEPI52Rejzk8s/edit?usp=sharing

its from (Colum A to Colum G)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've already made a list of unique dates in column I and you want to automatically fill in column J. You can use SUMIF. For `J3` it would be.

`=SUMIF(A:A, I3, B:B)`

This says, look for all of the rows in column A that contain the value in J:3. Add up the corresponding values from column B.

Comment: One thing I notice is that your date field has timestamps. You would have to remove those to use this solution.

Comment: Hi i removed it can u look at the file again i got an error . i would like to have the date in 1 cell and next to it the amounts total for that date. Cell F3 F4 and F5 (and counting of there are more orders comming in .

Comment: A couple of things: There was a mistake in my syntax, and your columns have moved around a bit: `=SUMIF(A:A, H3, F:F)` I also notice that you haven't removed the timestamps from column A, so it will return 0 as is.

Comment: FYI, here's a quick way to convert them. I tested it: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/mfoiRDosiKk you'll make a new column with the converted dates, so keep in mind you'll have to search on that column instead of A.

Comment: sorry i do not know what i am doing wrong but i still get an ERROR could u please review your awnser ?